# Regex Pattern Matching for similar URL

Tags: javascript, regex, mountebank

I need to send different Response for different urls. But the Regex that I am using is not working.

The two Regex in question is

```
"/v1/users/[^/]+/permissions/domain/HTTP/"
```

(Eg: http://localhost:4544/v1/users/10feec20-afd9-46a0-a3fc-9b2f18c1d363/permissions/domain/HTTP)

and

```
"/v1/users/[^/]+/"
```

(Eg: http://localhost:4544/v1/users/10feec20-afd9-46a0-a3fc-9b2f18c1d363)

I am not able to figure out how to stop the regex matching after "[^/]+/". Both the pattern return the same result. It is as if due to regex both of them are same URL's. The pattern matching happens in mountebank mocking server using a matching predicate. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the end anchor, `$`. Like: `"/v1/users/[^/]+/$"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `"/v1/users/[^/]+/"` matches both urls. You are asking it to match '/v1/users/` plus anything except '/' followed by a slash. This happens in both the longer URL and the short one, which is why it matches.

A couple options:

You can match the longer url and not the shorter one with:

```
"/v1/users/[^/]+/.+"
```

This matches http://localhost:4544/v1/users/10feec20-afd9-46a0-a3fc-9b2f18c1d363/permissions/domain/HTTP, but not http://localhost:4544/v1/users/10feec20-afd9-46a0-a3fc-9b2f18c1d363/

You could also match just the short one by anchoring the end:

```
"/v1/users/[^/]+/$"
```

This matches the short URL but not the long one.